# Why is this jQuery eq(i) NOT working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I discover that the for loop (i++) method only works in some cases in my projects and this is one of the cases that it does NOT work. I never knew why it doesn't work and still haven't found the answer.

I hope people around could help me out since this is starting to bring me problems. No matter if we do it with jQuery or with vanilla JS, as long as I could get through this problem.

I did a very small jFiddle, the real codes are larger and with ajax calls here and there but it is pretty much the same, I usually need to use the following (js script) INSIDE the ajax success, but I use something like "closest.find('.example)" instead, and for some reason I want to stop using that method.

https://jsfiddle.net/un12bjq3/1/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
button {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: midnightblue;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container,
.container_ {
  display: table;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.border_div {
  float: left;
  display: table;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="border_div">
  <h2>
With eq(i)..<br>Not working
</h2>
  <button class="btn">
    Btn 1
  </button>

  <div class="container">
    Container 1
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>

  <button class="btn">
    Btn 2
  </button>

  <div class="container">
    Container 2
  </div>

</div>







<div class="border_div">
  <h2>
Without eq(i)<br>It only works with<br>a real number
</h2>
  <button class="btn_">
    Btn 1
  </button>

  <div class="container_">
    Container 1
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>

  <button class="btn_">
    Btn 2
  </button>

  <div class="container_">
    Container 2
  </div>

</div>




<script>

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $('.btn').eq(i).click(function() {
    $('.container').eq(i).toggle();
  });
}



// How can I auto detect the eq() index ?
// This is a working example with eq(0)
$('.btn_').eq(0).click(function() {
  $('.container_').eq(0).toggle();
});
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p5deop0m/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `let` instead of `var`

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $('.btn').eq(i).click(function() {
    $('.container').eq(i).toggle();
  });
}
```

When using `var`, the variable i is shared between all iterations of the loop. When the event handler is then executed, it will have the value 5.

When using `let`, there is a new variable i in each loop iteration, so that each event uses the correct value of i.

---

You can actually use much simpler code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('.btn').eq(i).click(function() {
            $(this).toggle();
    });
}
```

jQuery makes sure that `this` refers to the correct element in an event handler.

Comment: this worked perfectly! Seems a question similar to mine was answered a few years ago. Thanks a lot, didn't know about "let". Pretty much the best day of the year so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.index`: https://api.jquery.com/index/

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var index = $(".btn").index (this);   
    $('.container').eq(index).toggle();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked too as well, is nice to have more than 1 method for the same purpose, didn't knew this method either, even though I'm not novice. Thanks a lot David.

Comment: You are welcome :)